# How to add text to the shapes in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am drawing `Circle` on an `WPF` window. The problem is that I am unable add `Text` to the `Circle`. The code is given below:

```
public Graphics()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    Ellipse myel = new Ellipse();
    SolidColorBrush mscb = new SolidColorBrush();
    mscb.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
    myel.Fill = mscb;
    myel.StrokeThickness = 2;
    myel.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    myel.Width = 100;
    myel.Height = 100;
    //string str = "hello";
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myel);
    this.Content = myStackPanel;
}
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: First of all i would recommend moving all that to XAML...

Comment: @H.B. Do you know any way to add text to the circle, and btw, I have to control it thorough C# code as its a necessity.

P.S: I am not very comfortable when it comes to XML! :-)

Comment: How can it be a necessity? (Also don't ask people in comments about giving an answer to the question...)

Comment: Actually I am developing a desktop application in wpf for avl_trees. The problem is that, I have to provide a graphical layout of the tree i.e edges, nodes ,data etc. That's why I have to add text to the nodes of the tree, which are circles in my case!

Comment: Still not any reason to shun XAML.

Answer (score 24):

Shapes are simply shapes, if you want to add text then add both the shape and a `TextBlock` with your text to a common container which lays them on top of each other, e.g. a `Grid` without rows or columns.

In XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Width="100" .../>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(new Ellipse { Width = 100, ... });
grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Lorem Ipsum" });
```

Comment: Sir, 

Can you please provide me an example on that? or can you provide me the code simply?

I have never dealt with graphics before.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use direct positioning in a Canvas if you prefer direct control over the draw position:

My sample defines a UI control that draws rectangles with text in it:

*XAML*:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DrawOnCanvas"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="DrawCanvas" Height="30"/>
</Grid>
```

*Code behind:*

```
    // You might e.g. call this in the constructor of DrawOnCanvas
    internal void DrawRectWithText()
    {
        var rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige);

        rect.Width = 100;
        rect.Height = 100;

        // Use Canvas's static methods to position the rectangle
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 100);

        var text = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = task.Title,
        };

        // Use Canvas's static methods to position the text
        Canvas.SetLeft(text, 90);
        Canvas.SetTop(text, 90);

        // Draw the rectange and the text to my Canvas control.
        // DrawCanvas is the name of my Canvas control in the XAML code
        DrawCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
        DrawCanvas.Children.Add(text);
    }
```